# Can't detect objects with using a radar sensor

Tags: python, webots

I'm trying to build my own robot model with radar sensor and detect other robots models in order to make my robot follow them. To implement, I attached a radar device to my robot and made a controller code. However, he couldn't detect any robot. What could be the cause in this case?? Parameters and the controller code are below.

```
#Radar Device's Parameter:
radarCrossSection: 1
minRange: 0.01
maxRange: 1
horizontalFOV: 1
verticalFOV: 0.5
occlusion: True

#Other Robot's Parameter:
radarCrossSection: 1
```

(Other parameters are default value.)

```
#Controller code:
import numpy as np
from controller import Robot, Radar

robot = Robot()
timestep = int(1.0)

radar = robot.getDevice('radar')
radar.enable(timestep)
radar_NOT = radar.getNumberOfTargets()
radar_targets = radar.getTargets()

while robot.step(timestep) != -1:
    print(radar_NOT)
    print(radar_targets)
```

The result I got is below:

```
0
[]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Radar works under principles of [doppler's effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect), and if my understanding is correct, it can only detect moving objects, or object with relative speed differs from your own. Have you tried enable movement for the other robot models? Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Ken Y-N!

I didn't write other robot's code, however I've already prepared. (and it works.)

Comment: I tried some additional approaches, but the radar device didn't work...

Comment: Can you further describe the additional approaches that you took? It may help debug the problem.

Comment: Additional approaches I tried are these:
1) Increase the parameter of other robot's radarCrossSection

2) Import RadarTarget in the controller code

3) Change the translation of radar device (in order to prevent from interfering my robot's body)

4) Update Webots (2021b → 2022a)

Above all approaches didn't work. I'm running out of ideas. :(

Comment: After I moved "while robot.step(timestep) != -1:" from behind "radar_targets = radar.getTargets()" to behind "timestep = int(1.0)", the radar device worked.

Thank you for thinking!